# How can I stack two same-sized canvas on top of each other, next to another canvas?

Tags: css, html, canvas

I been trying to get two same-sized canvas on top of each other and next to another canvas. Lets see, in the figure below I want 2 and 3 in the same place, next to 1.
[image]

I have tried to solve this problem with the following code:

```css
#plotCanvas {
  background-color: #fff;
  position: relative;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
}

#plotCanvas_BG {
  background-color: #fff;
  position: absolute;
  top: 329px;
  left: 352px;
  background-color: transparent;
}
```

```html
<div style="width: 810px; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;">
  <canvas width="350" height="350" id="imageCanvas" style="float: left; border: 1px solid black;"></canvas>
  <canvas width="350" height="350" id="plotCanvas" style="margin-left: 6px; border: 1px solid black;"></canvas>
  <canvas width="350" height="350" id="plotCanvas_BG" style="margin-left: 6px; border: 1px solid black;"></canvas>
</div>
```

As you can see, I have set the position of the canvas 3 (which corresponds to "plotCanvas_BG") manually. However,  the disadvantage is that the position of the canvas 3 is different depending on the web browser and if the size of the web page change, then the position also changes.

Comment: are you trying to display 1,2,3 in same line?

Comment: http://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/NrdWGz   - 2,3 in same line
http://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/NrdWGz - 1,3 in same line
http://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/XKprww - 1,2,3 in same line

Comment: Thanks for answer Naga Sai A. Yes, 1,2 and 3 must be in same line. However, I want 2 and 3 in the same position. In other words, I want 3 be a **layer** of canvas 2.

Comment: Hope the code in http://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/XKprww works for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a container div that is positioned relative that will contain the canvas elements positioned absolute.

```
<div style="width: 810px; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;">
  <canvas width="350" height="350" id="imageCanvas" style="float: left; border: 1px solid black;"></canvas>
  <div class="container">
    <canvas width="350" height="350" id="plotCanvas" style="margin-left: 6px; border: 1px solid black;"></canvas>
    <canvas width="350" height="350" id="plotCanvas_BG" style="margin-left: 6px; border: 1px solid black;"></canvas>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.container {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  float: left;
}

#plotCanvas,
#plotCanvas_BG {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: transparent;
}

#plotCanvas {
  background-color: #fff;
}
```

**JSFiddle Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/8c8csnzk/1/**

Answer (score 1):

Increase width of div

```
    <div style="width: 1150px; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;">
div canvas{
  display:inline-block;
}
```

http://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/XKprww

Comment: To differentiate the canvas and for testing, i have used different background colors ,white for canvas-1, green for canvas2 and red for canvas3 .. :)